# IllegalArgumentException when lists are full

Tags: java, arraylist, error-handling, illegalargumentexception, throw

For some reason, I keep getting errors at these particular lines. The lists do have indexes, but for some odd reason, it gives me this error when I try to run it.

Here's the error it throws and said lines.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be 
positive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Room.getRandomEnemy(Room.java:95)
at Room.<init>(Room.java:32)
at Game.startGame(Game.java:102)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Here is my code.

```
static ArrayList<String> enemys = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Red minion", "Blue Minion", "Purple Minion", "Blitz", "Katarina", "Green Minion")); 
private String contents; 
static ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Mana Potion", "Health Potion", "Pickaxe", "Cloth-Armor", "Cull"));

int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(enemys.size());
this.getRandomEnemy(enemys);
Room inhibitor1 = new Room("inhibitor1", inhibitor1Desc, inhibi1Exit, 
console);
game.startGame();
```

Comment: `enemys.size()` returns 0, probably because you have no enemies, lucky one

Comment: static ArrayList<String> enemys = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Red 
    minion", "Blue Minion", "Purple Minion", "Blitz", "Katarina", "Green 
    Minion"));

that's the code for my enemies list.

Comment: either you're using different `enemys` variable or somebody cleared the list

Answer (score 0):

@Lashane is right!

[image]

If your enemies list is empty, it will return 0, hence Random.nextInt() will throw IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: however, my enemies list is not empty.

Comment: Show us code, where you initialized your enemies. Because definitely your list is empty.

Comment: static ArrayList<String> enemys = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Red minion", "Blue Minion", "Purple Minion", "Blitz", "Katarina", "Green Minion")); 
private String contents;
static ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Mana Potion",  "Health Potion", "Pickaxe", "Cloth-Armor", "Cull"));

Comment: Something is not right, either you are using a different variable or your enemys arraylist is cleared till it reached your Random.nextInt() method. There is no other way, it would throw IllegalArgumentException. Try to debug it step by step.